# Can a simple counter not go negative in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

I have two dictionaries:

```
members_singles = {'member3': ['PCP3'], 'member4': ['PCP1'], 'member11': ['PCP2'], 'member12': 
['PCP3'], 'member14': ['PCP4'], 'member15': ['PCP4'], 'member16': ['PCP4'], 'members17': ['PCP3']}

providers = {
"PCP1" : 3,
"PCP2" : 4,
"PCP3" : 1,
"PCP4" : 2,
"PCP5" : 4,
}
```

I want to iterate through `members` and each time a particular value occurs, count down one from the matching count in `providers`

```
to_remove_zero = []
pcps_in_negative = []
for member, provider_list in members_singles.items():
    provider = provider_list[0]
    if provider in providers:
        providers[provider] -= 1
        if providers[provider] == 0:
            to_remove_zero.append(provider)
        elif providers[provider] < 0:
            pcps_in_negative.append(provider)
        else:
            pass
```

I want to save those providers that end up with an even zero count to a list and save those providers that go in the negative to another list.  But my results show `to_remove_zero` contains ['PCP3', 'PCP4'] even though they should be in the negative.  So the loop is popping them out before they get to the second condition.  Does python simple counters like this stop at zero when counting down or am I missing something?

Comment: In first snippet you mention "members_singles". In second there is "members_with_one_choice". Are they related?

Comment: Yes sorry in reality there were the same but I forgot to change them in my quesiton to be the same

Comment: @Greg gave the right answer: If a provider reaches 0 it is removed from "providers" and can't be decremented further.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I have edited my original question and remove the 'pop' command.  It still doesnt count below zero and do what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `providers` count reaches zero, your code adds the provider to the `to_remove_zero` list. But the count may go negative later on, which will add the same provider to the `pcps_in_negative` list. At that point, your code needs to back-track and remove it from the `to_remove_zero` list:

```
providers[provider] -= 1
if providers[provider] == 0:
    to_remove_zero.append(provider)
elif providers[provider] < 0:
    pcps_in_negative.append(provider)
    # back-track
    if provider in to_remove_zero:
        to_remove_zero.remove(provider)
```

This could be made a little neater if you used sets:

```
to_remove_zero = set()
pcps_in_negative = set()
for member, provider_list in members_singles.items():
    provider = provider_list[0]
    if provider in providers:
        providers[provider] -= 1
        if providers[provider] == 0:
            to_remove_zero.add(provider)
        elif providers[provider] < 0:
            pcps_in_negative.add(provider)
            to_remove_zero.discard(provider)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because you are altering the list, while expecting the indices to remain consistent:

```
a = [1,2,3]
a[0]
# 1
a.pop()
# 3
a[0]
# 1
```

Comment: Even if I dont pop them out and alter the original providers object, its appending PCPs and PCP4 to the zeros list when it should be negative

Comment: I'm not popping a list, I am popping a dictionary.  A dictionary doesnt have indices like that

Comment: @BenSmith During counting down to negative it reaches zero which triggers appending to the zeros list. Move adding to zero and subzero lists to a second loop over "providers" after the first loop